# LDAP search helper for System.DirectoryServices.Protocols

Tags: c#, ldap

Given all the times I need to perform LDAP searches in the work I do, I wrote a helper and I want to clean it up and publish it to Nuget. What are peoples opinions of the approaches used?

```
namespace MyCompany.Directory.LDAP
{
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an LDAP entry.
    /// </summary>
    public class LdapEntry : IReadOnlyDictionary<string, LdapAttribute>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for Attributes.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<string, LdapAttribute> attributes;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for DistinguishedName.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string distinguishedName;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LdapEntry" /> structure.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="distinguishedName">The distinguished name for the entry.</param>
        /// <param name="attributes">The attributes for the entry.</param>
        public LdapEntry(string distinguishedName, IDictionary<string, LdapAttribute> attributes)
        {
            this.distinguishedName = distinguishedName;
            this.attributes = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, LdapAttribute>(attributes);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the attributes for the entry.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The <see cref="LdapAttribute"/>s for the <see cref="LdapEntry"/>.</value>
        public ReadOnlyDictionary<string, LdapAttribute> Attributes => this.attributes;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the number of elements in the collection.
        /// </summary>
        public int Count => this.attributes.Count;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the distinguished name for the entry.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The distinguished name for the entry.</value>
        public string DistinguishedName => this.distinguishedName;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets an enumerable collection that contains the attribute types in the <see cref="LdapEntry"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<string> Keys => this.attributes.Keys;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets an enumerable collection that contains the <see cref="LdapAttribute"/>s in the <see cref="LdapEntry"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<LdapAttribute> Values => this.attributes.Values;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the <see cref="LdapAttribute"/> that has the specified attribute type in the <see cref="LdapEntry"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The <see cref="LdapAttribute"/> to locate.</param>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="LdapAttribute"/> that has the specified attribute type in the <see cref="LdapEntry"/>.</returns>
        public LdapAttribute this[string key] => this.attributes[key];

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the <see cref="LdapEntry"/> contains an attribute type that has the specified name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The attribute type to locate.</param>
        /// <returns><b>true</b> if the <see cref="LdapEntry"/> contains an attribute type that has the specified name; otherwise, <b>false</b>.</returns>
        public bool ContainsKey(string key) => this.attributes.ContainsKey(key);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection of <see cref="LdapAttribute"/>s.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An enumerator that can be used to iterate through the collection of <see cref="LdapAttribute"/>s.</returns>
        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, LdapAttribute>> GetEnumerator() => this.attributes.GetEnumerator();

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection of <see cref="LdapAttribute"/>s.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An enumerator that can be used to iterate through the collection of <see cref="LdapAttribute"/>s.</returns>
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value that is associated with the specified attribute type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The attribute type to locate.</param>
        /// <param name="value">
        /// When this method returns, the value associated with the specified attribute type, if the attribute namer is found;
        /// otherwise, the default value for the type of the value parameter. This parameter is passed uninitialized.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns><b>true</b> if the <see cref="LdapEntry"/> contains an attribute type that has the specified name; otherwise, <b>false</b>.</returns>
        public bool TryGetValue(string key, out LdapAttribute value) => this.attributes.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }
}

namespace MyCompany.Directory.LDAP
{
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an LDAP attribute type with both decoded and encoded values.
    /// </summary>
    public struct LdapAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for Name.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string name;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for decoded data.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> values;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for encoded data.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<byte[]> valuesBytes;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LdapAttribute" /> structure.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The attribute type.</param>
        /// <param name="values">The decoded attribute values.</param>
        /// <param name="valuesBytes">The encoded attribute values.</param>
        public LdapAttribute(string name, IEnumerable<string> values, IEnumerable<byte[]> valuesBytes)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.values = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(values.ToList());
            this.valuesBytes = new ReadOnlyCollection<byte[]>(valuesBytes.ToList());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the attribute type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The attribute type.</value>
        public string Name => this.name;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the first decoded value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The first decoded value.</value>
        public string Value => this.values[0];

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the first encoded value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The first encoded value.</value>
        public byte[] ValueBytes => this.valuesBytes[0];

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the collection of decoded values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The collection of decoded values.</value>
        public ReadOnlyCollection<string> Values => this.values;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the collection of encoded values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The collection of encoded values.</value>
        public ReadOnlyCollection<byte[]> ValuesBytes => this.valuesBytes;
    }
}


namespace MyCompany.Directory.LDAP
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;
    using System.Globalization;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an LDAP search class supporting paged results and automatic ranged attribute retrieval.
    /// </summary>
    public class LdapSearch
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The associated LDAP connection.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly LdapConnection ldapConnection;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for AttributeList.
        /// </summary>
        private IEnumerable<string> attributeList;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for BaseDn.
        /// </summary>
        private string baseDn;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for LdapFilter.
        /// </summary>
        private string ldapFilter;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for PageSize.
        /// </summary>
        private int pageSize;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for RangedRetrieval.
        /// </summary>
        private bool rangedRetrieval;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for Referrals.
        /// </summary>
        private bool referrals;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for SearchScope.
        /// </summary>
        private SearchScope searchScope;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private backing field for SizeLimit.
        /// </summary>
        private int sizeLimit;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LdapSearch"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ldapConnection"></param>
        public LdapSearch(LdapConnection ldapConnection) => this.ldapConnection = ldapConnection;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value representing the attribute list to retrieve during a search operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The attribute list to retrieve during a search operation.</value>
        public IEnumerable<string> AttributeList
        {
            get => this.attributeList;

            set => this.attributeList = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value representing the object at which to start the search.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The object at which to start the search.</value>
        public string BaseDn
        {
            get => this.baseDn;

            set => this.baseDn = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value representing the LDAP search filter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The LDAP search filter.</value>
        public string LdapFilter
        {
            get => this.ldapFilter;

            set => this.ldapFilter = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value representing the size of the paged results control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The size of the paged results control, 0 disabled the control.</value>
        public int PageSize
        {
            get => this.pageSize;

            set => this.pageSize = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether ranged retrieval is enabled.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value><true>true</true> if ranged retrieval is enabled, otherwise <b>false</b>.</value>
        public bool RangedRetrieval
        {
            get => this.rangedRetrieval;

            set => this.rangedRetrieval = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether referrals are enabled.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value><true>true</true> if referrals are enabled, otherwise <b>false</b>.</value>
        public bool Referrals
        {
            get => this.referrals;

            set => this.referrals = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value representing the scope of a search.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The scope of a search.</value>
        public SearchScope SearchScope
        {
            get => this.searchScope;

            set => this.searchScope = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating the maximum number of entries the directory service agent will return when answering a search request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The maximum number of entries the directory service agent will return when answering a search request.</value>
        public int SizeLimit
        {
            get => this.sizeLimit;

            set => this.sizeLimit = value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initiates the LDAP search.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The LDAP search result set.</returns>
        public IEnumerable<LdapEntry> Search()
        {
            // Validate search request requirements.
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.baseDn))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(this.BaseDn), "The BaseDn must be specified.");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ldapFilter))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(this.LdapFilter), "The LDAP filter must be specified.");
            }

            // Setup search request.
            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(
                this.baseDn,
                this.ldapFilter,
                this.searchScope,
                this.attributeList as string[]);

            // Configure size limit.
            if (this.sizeLimit > 0)
            {
                searchRequest.SizeLimit = this.sizeLimit;
            }

            // Configure referrals.
            if (!this.referrals)
            {
                SearchOptionsControl searchOptions = new SearchOptionsControl(SearchOption.DomainScope);
                searchRequest.Controls.Add(searchOptions);
            }

            // Assign search delegate.
            Func<SearchRequest, IEnumerable<SearchResultEntry>> searchFunc;
            if (this.pageSize > 0)
            {
                // Paged search enabled.
                searchFunc = this.SearchPaged;
            }
            else
            {
                // Simple search enabled.
                searchFunc = this.SearchSimple;
            }

            // Assign parser delegate.
            Func<SearchResultEntry, Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute>> parser;
            if (this.RangedRetrieval)
            {
                parser = searchResultEntry => this.ParseSearchResultEntryRanged(searchFunc, searchResultEntry);
            }
            else
            {
                parser = this.ParseSearchResultEntry;
            }

            // Invoke search.
            foreach (SearchResultEntry searchResultEntry in searchFunc(searchRequest))
            {
                Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute> attributes = parser(searchResultEntry);

                yield return new LdapEntry(searchResultEntry.DistinguishedName, attributes);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Detects if an attribute type returned by the directory has had ranged retrieval invoked.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="attributeType">The attribute type returned by the directory to parse.</param>
        /// <param name="attributeTypeActual">The actual parsed name.</param>
        /// <param name="start">The start range, or 0 if unavailable.</param>
        /// <param name="end">The end range, or 0 if unavailable or if the range is complete.</param>
        /// <returns><true>true</true> if the directory has had invoked ranged retrieval, otherwise <b>false</b>.</returns>
        private bool ParseRange(string attributeType, out string attributeTypeActual, out ulong start, out ulong end)
        {
            // Validate input.
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attributeType))
            {
                throw new LdapException("Directory returned to an invalid attribute type.");
            }

            // Detect if directory has invoked range retrieval.
            int rangeIndex = attributeType.IndexOf(";range=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (rangeIndex == -1)
            {
                attributeTypeActual = attributeType;
                start = 0;
                end = 0;

                return false;
            }

            // Update actual attribute type.
            attributeTypeActual = attributeType.Substring(0, rangeIndex);

            // Extract range start and end.
            string[] range = attributeType
                .Substring(rangeIndex + 7)
                .Split('-');

            if (range.Length != 2)
            {
                throw new LdapException("Failed to parse ranged attribute.");
            }

            string rangeStartString = range[0];
            string rangeEndString = range[1];

            // Parse start value.
            if (!ulong.TryParse(rangeStartString, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ulong rangeStart))
            {
                throw new LdapException("Failed to parse start of ranged attribute.");
            }

            // Detect end of range or parse end value if needed.
            if (rangeEndString == "*")
            {
                start = 0;
                end = 0;

                return false;
            }

            if (!ulong.TryParse(rangeEndString, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ulong rangeEnd))
            {
                throw new LdapException("Failed to parse end of ranged attribute.");
            }

            start = rangeStart;
            end = rangeEnd;

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the <see cref="DirectoryAttribute"/>s from a search result into <see cref="LdapAttribute"/>s.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="searchResultEntry">The search result entry to convert.</param>
        /// <returns>The entries LDAP attributes.</returns>
        private Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute> ParseSearchResultEntry(SearchResultEntry searchResultEntry)
        {
            Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute> ldapAttributes = new Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute>();

            if (searchResultEntry?.Attributes?.Values == null)
            {
                return ldapAttributes;
            }

            // Collect raw attribute values.
            Dictionary<string, Tuple<List<string>, List<byte[]>>> rawAttributes = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<List<string>, List<byte[]>>>();
            foreach (DirectoryAttribute directoryAttribute in searchResultEntry.Attributes.Values)
            {
                // Prepare collection references.
                List<string> valuesString;
                List<byte[]> valuesByte;
                Tuple<List<string>, List<byte[]>> rawAttribute;
                if (rawAttributes.TryGetValue(directoryAttribute.Name, out rawAttribute))
                {
                    valuesString = rawAttribute.Item1;
                    valuesByte = rawAttribute.Item2;
                }
                else
                {
                    valuesString = new List<string>();
                    valuesByte = new List<byte[]>();
                    rawAttribute = new Tuple<List<string>, List<byte[]>>(valuesString, valuesByte);
                    rawAttributes.Add(directoryAttribute.Name, rawAttribute);
                }

                // Collect initial appearance of values.
                valuesString.AddRange((string[])directoryAttribute.GetValues(typeof(string)));
                valuesByte.AddRange((byte[][])directoryAttribute.GetValues(typeof(byte[])));
            }

            // Create LDAP attributes.
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<List<string>, List<byte[]>>> rawAttribute in rawAttributes)
            {
                LdapAttribute ldapAttribute = new LdapAttribute(rawAttribute.Key, rawAttribute.Value.Item1, rawAttribute.Value.Item2);
                ldapAttributes.Add(rawAttribute.Key, ldapAttribute);
            }

            return ldapAttributes;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the <see cref="DirectoryAttribute"/>s from a search result into <see cref="LdapAttribute"/>s with automatic ranged retrieval.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="searchFunc">The configured search implementation for ranged retrieval.</param>
        /// <param name="searchResultEntry">The search result entry to convert.</param>
        /// <returns>The entries LDAP attributes.</returns>
        private Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute> ParseSearchResultEntryRanged(Func<SearchRequest, IEnumerable<SearchResultEntry>> searchFunc, SearchResultEntry searchResultEntry)
        {
            Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute> ldapAttributes = new Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute>();

            if (searchResultEntry?.Attributes?.Values == null)
            {
                return ldapAttributes;
            }

            // Collect raw attribute values.
            Dictionary<string, Tuple<List<string>, List<byte[]>>> rawAttributes = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<List<string>, List<byte[]>>>();
            foreach (DirectoryAttribute directoryAttribute in searchResultEntry.Attributes.Values)
            {
                string attributeTypeActual;
                ulong start;
                ulong end;
                bool rangedRetrievalEnabled = this.ParseRange(directoryAttribute.Name, out attributeTypeActual, out start, out end);

                // Prepare collection references.
                List<string> valuesString;
                List<byte[]> valuesByte;
                Tuple<List<string>, List<byte[]>> rawAttribute;
                if (rawAttributes.TryGetValue(attributeTypeActual, out rawAttribute))
                {
                    valuesString = rawAttribute.Item1;
                    valuesByte = rawAttribute.Item2;
                }
                else
                {
                    valuesString = new List<string>();
                    valuesByte = new List<byte[]>();
                    rawAttribute = new Tuple<List<string>, List<byte[]>>(valuesString, valuesByte);
                    rawAttributes.Add(attributeTypeActual, rawAttribute);
                }

                // Collect initial values.
                valuesString.AddRange((string[])directoryAttribute.GetValues(typeof(string)));
                valuesByte.AddRange((byte[][])directoryAttribute.GetValues(typeof(byte[])));

                if (!rangedRetrievalEnabled)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Directory has invoked range retrieval, query the remaining values.
                do
                {
                    // Setup search request for the next range interval.
                    string rangedAttribute = $"{attributeTypeActual};range={end + 1}-*";
                    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(
                        searchResultEntry.DistinguishedName,
                        "(objectClass=*)",
                        SearchScope.Base,
                        rangedAttribute);

                    // Ensure one search result entry was returned without enumerating the entire collection.
                    SearchResultEntry rangedSearchResultEntry = null;
                    foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in searchFunc(searchRequest))
                    {
                        if (rangedSearchResultEntry != null)
                        {
                            throw new LdapException("Directory returned to many search results during ranged retrieval.");
                        }

                        rangedSearchResultEntry = entry;
                    }

                    if (rangedSearchResultEntry == null)
                    {
                        throw new LdapException("Directory did not return any search results during ranged retrieval.");
                    }

                    // Validate search result was for the object queried.
                    if (!rangedSearchResultEntry.DistinguishedName.Equals(searchResultEntry.DistinguishedName))
                    {
                        throw new LdapException("Directory returned an unexpected distinguished name during ranged retrieval.");
                    }

                    // Validate attribute data was returned.
                    if (rangedSearchResultEntry.Attributes?.Values == null)
                    {
                        throw new LdapException("Directory did not return any attribute types during ranged retrieval.");
                    }

                    if (rangedSearchResultEntry.Attributes.Values.Count != 1)
                    {
                        throw new LdapException("Directory returned invalid data during ranged retrieval.");
                    }

                    DirectoryAttribute[] rangedDirectoryAttributes = new DirectoryAttribute[rangedSearchResultEntry.Attributes.Values.Count];
                    rangedSearchResultEntry.Attributes.Values.CopyTo(rangedDirectoryAttributes, 0);

                    DirectoryAttribute rangedDirectoryAttribute = rangedDirectoryAttributes[0];

                    string attributeTypeTmp;
                    this.ParseRange(rangedDirectoryAttribute.Name, out attributeTypeTmp, out start, out end);

                    // Validate attribute type was for the type queried.
                    if (!attributeTypeTmp.Equals(attributeTypeActual))
                    {
                        throw new LdapException("Directory returned an unexpected distinguished name during ranged retrieval.");
                    }

                    valuesString.AddRange((string[])rangedDirectoryAttribute.GetValues(typeof(string)));
                    valuesByte.AddRange((byte[][])rangedDirectoryAttribute.GetValues(typeof(byte[])));
                } while (end != 0);
            }

            // Create LDAP attributes.
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<List<string>, List<byte[]>>> rawAttribute in rawAttributes)
            {
                LdapAttribute ldapAttribute = new LdapAttribute(rawAttribute.Key, rawAttribute.Value.Item1, rawAttribute.Value.Item2);
                ldapAttributes.Add(rawAttribute.Key, ldapAttribute);
            }

            return ldapAttributes;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Paged search implementation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="searchRequest">The configured search request.</param>
        /// <returns>Yields the results as a SearchResultEntry.</returns>
        private IEnumerable<SearchResultEntry> SearchPaged(SearchRequest searchRequest)
        {
            // Configure paging.
            PageResultRequestControl pageResultRequestControl = new PageResultRequestControl(this.pageSize);
            searchRequest.Controls.Add(pageResultRequestControl);

            while (true)
            {
                SearchResponse searchResponse = (SearchResponse)this.ldapConnection.SendRequest(searchRequest);

                if (searchResponse == null)
                {
                    break;
                }

                PageResultResponseControl pageResponse;
                if (searchResponse.Controls.Length != 1
                    || (pageResponse = searchResponse.Controls[0] as PageResultResponseControl) == null)
                {
                    throw new LdapException("Directory server returned an invalid page response.");
                }

                foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in searchResponse.Entries)
                {
                    yield return entry;
                }

                if (pageResponse.Cookie.Length == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                pageResultRequestControl.Cookie = pageResponse.Cookie;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Non paged search implementation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="searchRequest">The configured search request.</param>
        /// <returns>Yields the results as a SearchResultEntry.</returns>
        private IEnumerable<SearchResultEntry> SearchSimple(SearchRequest searchRequest)
        {
            SearchResponse searchResponse = (SearchResponse)this.ldapConnection.SendRequest(searchRequest);

            if (searchResponse == null)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in searchResponse.Entries)
            {
                yield return entry;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any programmatic improvements people can see, or any bad practices that more seasoned people spot? To use it:

```
LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(
    new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("172.18.0.50", 389),
    new NetworkCredential("CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=my-domain,DC=com", "SuperSecret"))
{
    AuthType = AuthType.Basic,
    Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
};
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOptions.None;

string baseDn = "OU=Lab,DC=my-domain,DC=com";
string ldapFilter = "(objectClass=group)";
SearchScope searchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
string[] attributeList = { "member", "objectClass", "sAMAccountName" };
int pageSize = 1000;
int sizeLimit = 2000;

LdapSearch ldapSearch = new LdapSearch(ldapConnection)
{
    BaseDn = baseDn,
    LdapFilter = ldapFilter,
    SearchScope = searchScope,
    SizeLimit = sizeLimit,
    AttributeList = attributeList,
    PageSize = pageSize
};

foreach (LdapEntry ldapEntry in ldapSearch.Search())
{
    Console.WriteLine(ldapEntry.DistinguishedName);
    foreach (LdapAttribute ldapAttribute in ldapEntry.Attributes.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"    * {ldapAttribute.Name}: {ldapAttribute.Values.Count}");
        //foreach (string value in ldapAttribute.Values)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine($"        - \"{value}\"");
        //}
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: God how I hate those useless comments. One of our branch offices uses StyleCop rules to enforce these comments must exist for every single thing. If this isn't enforced then delete them from your code immediately.

Comment: Well, style guidelines enforce consistency, you take the good with the bad. In the end, they contribute to a net benefit. I don't love them all but in this case, those comments help auto generated help docs.

Comment: All your properties are simple reads/writes to respective backing fields. Replace them with auto-properties and cut down the boilerplate.

Comment: You're also missing code - methods such as:

    `CreateLdapSearch()`
    `UseBaseDn(baseDn)`
    `UseLdapFilter(filter)`
    `UseScope(scope)`
    `UseSizeLimit(sizeLimit)`
    `UseAttributeList(attributes)`
    `UsePaging(pageSize)`
    `UseRangedRetrieval()`

aren't there.

Comment: I mentioned the usage of extensions in the last section, however I should not have been lazy. I have used an initializer.

Comment: I hate autogenerated docs that are for worth nothing (this is a constructor, this is a property, this is another obvious thing - great, like I didn't know it yet). I prefer a readme with examples about how to use _the damn thing_ rather then 10 pages of API description without a single use case.

Comment: You're misusing LdapException, which has a very specific meaning: The LdapException class is an exception that occurs when LDAP returns an error code not included in ResultCode.

Comment: When did the "get/set" syntax of C# change to `get => return obj;` and `set => obj = value;`? Does that offer any performance advantage from traditional ` get { return obj; }` and `set { obj = value; }`? It seems more confusing to read, but that could just be me.

Comment: You can read up about the different use cases at [lambda-operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator). As for the usage you're asking, The link suggests "Expression body definitions for methods and property get statements are supported starting with C# 6. Expression body definitions for constructors, finalizers, property set statements, and indexers are supported starting with C# 7."

Answer (score 3):

1. You have too much unnecessary comments such as - *Private backing field for ...*, you don't really care about the backing field of a property anyway.
2. Convert your properties into auto properties like this:

> ```
> private bool rangedRetrieval;
> public bool RangedRetrieval
> {
>     get => return rangedRetrieval;
>     set => rangedRetrieval = value;
> }
> ```

Can be shorten to:

```
public bool RangedRetrieval { get; set; }
```

You can do the same for all of your properties.

3. This looks pretty crazy `Dictionary<string, Tuple<List<string>, List<byte[]>>>` and you're using this in a few places so it might be a good idea to make `Tuple<List<string>, List<byte[]>>` a class, the type name will be shorter and you will actually have normal names instead of `Item1` and `Item2`. Say:

   ```
   public class RawAttribute
   {
       public List<string> AttributeStrings { get; set; }
       public List<byte[]> AttributeBytes { get; set; }

       public RawAttribute(List<string> attributeStrings, List<byte[]> attributeBytes)
       {
           AttributeStrings = attributeStrings;
           AttributeBytes = attributeBytes;
       }
   }
   ```

   Of course you should come up with proper names for the properties.

   You can adapt this to your other classes e.g:

   > ```
   > public LdapAttribute(string name, IEnumerable<string> values, IEnumerable<byte[]> valuesBytes)
   >  {
   >      Name = name;
   >      Values = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(values.ToList());
   >      ValuesBytes = new ReadOnlyCollection<byte[]>(valuesBytes.ToList());
   >  }
   > ```

   You can make the constructor accept `RawAttribute` and so you can shorten the initialisation and you can also replace `Values` &&  `ValuesBytes` by just a single instance of `RawAttribute`.
4. `ParseSearchResultEntryRanged` is way too long and you also have `ParseSearchResultEntry`, those 2 methods share lots of similarities I would image the first one making use of the later to reduce the code size. If that's not possible you can at least extract the repetitive code in method and just use that.

   Here is an example of how `ParseSearchResultEntry` can look:

   ```
   private Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute> ParseSearchResultEntry(SearchResultEntry searchResultEntry)
   {
       Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute> ldapAttributes = new Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute>();

       if (searchResultEntry?.Attributes?.Values == null)
       {
           return ldapAttributes;
       }

       // Collect raw attribute values.
       Dictionary<string, RawAttribute> rawAttributes = new Dictionary<string, RawAttribute>();
       foreach (DirectoryAttribute directoryAttribute in searchResultEntry.Attributes.Values)
       {
           // Prepare collection references.
           RawAttribute rawAttribute;
           if (!rawAttributes.TryGetValue(directoryAttribute.Name, out rawAttribute))
           {
               rawAttribute = new RawAttribute(new List<string>(), new List<byte[]>());
               rawAttributes.Add(directoryAttribute.Name, rawAttribute);
           }

           // Collect initial appearance of values.
           rawAttribute.AttributeStrings.AddRange((string[])directoryAttribute.GetValues(typeof(string)));
           rawAttribute.AttributeBytes.AddRange((byte[][])directoryAttribute.GetValues(typeof(byte[])));
       }

       // Create LDAP attributes.
       foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RawAttribute> rawAttribute in rawAttributes)
       {
           LdapAttribute ldapAttribute = new LdapAttribute(rawAttribute.Key, rawAttribute.Value);
           ldapAttributes.Add(rawAttribute.Key, ldapAttribute);
       }

       return ldapAttributes;
   }
   ```

   As you can see I've flipped the `if` statement since you only care about your original `else` body and I'm making use of the class' properties rather than some extra variables. You can apply the same to `ParseSearchResultEntryRanged`.
5. There are some places where you can use the ternary operator instead of `if/else`

   > ```
   > Func<SearchRequest, IEnumerable<SearchResultEntry>> searchFunc;
   > if (PageSize > 0)
   > {
   >     // Paged search enabled.
   >     searchFunc = SearchPaged;
   > }
   > else
   > {
   >     // Simple search enabled.
   >     searchFunc = SearchSimple;
   > }
   >
   > // Assign parser delegate.
   > Func<SearchResultEntry, Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute>> parser;
   > if (RangedRetrieval)
   > {
   >     parser = searchResultEntry => ParseSearchResultEntryRanged(searchFunc, searchResultEntry);
   > }
   > else
   > {
   >     parser = ParseSearchResultEntry;
   > }
   > ```

   Can be written like this:

   ```
     // Assign search delegate.
     var searchFunc = PageSize > 0
         ? (Func<SearchRequest, IEnumerable<SearchResultEntry>>) SearchPaged
         : SearchSimple;

     // Assign parser delegate.
     var parser = RangedRetrieval
         ? (Func<SearchResultEntry, Dictionary<string, LdapAttribute>>)
         (searchResultEntry => ParseSearchResultEntryRanged(searchFunc, searchResultEntry))
         : ParseSearchResultEntry;
   ```
6. To me this isn't clear:

   > ```
   > SearchResultEntry rangedSearchResultEntry = null;
   > foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in searchFunc(searchRequest))
   > {
   >     if (rangedSearchResultEntry != null)
   >     {
   >         throw new LdapException("Directory returned to many search results during ranged retrieval.");
   >     }
   >
   >     rangedSearchResultEntry = entry;
   > }
   >
   > if (rangedSearchResultEntry == null)
   > {
   >     throw new LdapException("Directory did not return any search results during ranged retrieval.");
   > }
   > ```

   Also your second exception *"Directory returned to many search results during ranged retrieval."* seems kinda odd, are you excluding the possibility of having a item with value null? This is how I would write it:

   ```
   var searchResult = searchFunc(searchRequest);
   if (searchResult.Skip(1).Any())
   {
       throw new LdapException("Directory returned to many search results during ranged retrieval.");
   }
   var rangedSearchResultEntry = searchResult.FirstOrDefault();
   if (rangedSearchResultEntry == null)
   {
       throw new LdapException("Directory did not return any search results during ranged retrieval.");
   }
   ```

There is probably more to cover but a good start would be to try shortening your methods as much as possible and make good use of what you already have. Why write the same code twice when you can write it only once?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great detail.

For 5, that won't compile as I do not think you can assign delegates with ternary's.

For 6, this is to adhere to the spec. If the return is null (not possible by framework design) then a problem occurred. If more than one value exists in the collection, then a violation of spec has occurred in the directory. The issue with the underlying collection is that it is an enumerable so we can not know how many items if any exist.

To be honest, after benching some changes that I introduced, I have removed all Linq as it's slower than traditional approaches.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it? The LINQ operations used in 6.are really fast the difference between normal foreach should be negligable.

Comment: Please take a closet look at point 5. It wouldn't work if we didn't have the casting there.

Comment: For point 5, I missed the nuance of at least one explicit cast. Sorry about that, it does compile. Very interesting!

Comment: For point 6, I certainly did bench it. Its actually a rare case where you can generalize that a linq approach is *always* slower. Your approach yields a normalized mean of 1359.542825ms over 10m runs, mine is 602.16395ms, and another approach I tried invoking the Enumerator manually resulted in 584.9351ms. Your approach also needs null checks to prevent an NRE on accessing the linq methods.

Comment: @Ritmo2k I'm not saying LINQ is faster or even equal in speed but jugging by your benchmarks you're loosing about ~1ms every second, this is negligible, it seems like a no-brainer to me  to pick better looking and easier to read code at the cost of ~1ms every second. This is just my opinion and I'm suggesting you what I feel is better you can always just skip through some tips you don't like :).

Comment: @Ritmo2k if performance is important for you try to set the [tag:performance] tag next time. Usually without it, people (me included) don't care about the small LINQ overhead as it might then be neglected and convenience goes before performance.